# Is there an administrator account available for google calendar api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I use this google calendar api code to develop(You can find the code [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python#troubleshooting)):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('./credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary',timeMin=now,).execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I use the calendar API to develop, the first time I click the page's permission button,then the pycharm console can return the output.

Is there an administrator account that can control the accounts of more than 100 people? Such as our company has 100 people, if I want to get the data of 100 people, do I need to get 100 people's account information(Gmail account and password) and credentials.json files?

When I first run the code for everyone's credentials.json file, I need to click 100 times 'admit' for 100 people,that's not good. I hope to have administrator privileges to simplify this operation.

Is there an administrator account that can control these 100 people? Do I need to download 100 people's credentials.json files?

Which one should I click to do the next step, how can I get json file of everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the administrator information [page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60217?#add_more).

Use the administrator account login.

Download the administrator's credentials.json.

Use administrator account to add gmail address likes this,enter fmail address:
[image]

Then click `Settings and sharing`, then You'll find the calendarId.
[image]

If your company has 20 people, repeat this operation 20 times, and then put the calendarId of 20 people to the list and loop it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called [G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation). Directly from the linked guide:

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access a user's data without any manual authorization on their part. In G Suite domains, the domain administrator can grant third-party applications with domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks!Is there any code or api for administrator to manipulate json files?

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure what you mean by "manipulate json files". Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Hi,"manipulate json files" means I'm not an administrator now, I need to loop 100 people's JSON files to get the calendar data of everyone.
For example,the 1st person's json file is named credentials_1.json,the 2nd person's json file is named credentials_2.json,and so on.If I have a administrator account,how could I change my code and where do I need to modify?